# While loop fail, when reading int and string C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, cout, cin

I'm trying to read multiple `Strings` and `ints` from the user. I want to take pairs of Name and Age and keep doing it until the user types in "done". But my `do-while` crashes early on, and i can't figure out why?

```
int number;
string name;
do
{
cout << "Your name: " ;
getline(cin, name);    
cout <<name<< " age: " ;
cin >> number;
}
 while (name!="done");
```

Edit: Also after entering "done", i have to enter "done" also on age, why is that?

Comment: Whats your input when it crashes?

Comment: I'm wondering it's just you key in some NaN value when asking age

Comment: I can enter two values once, name and age, but the second time, it prints my last input 1 million times..

Comment: "crashes"?  Care to elaborate?

Comment: it prints the thing you last entered over and over again until you terminate the program...

Comment: The getline reads up to and including new line, the cin >> doesn't take the newline off the stream. When you enter done as the age, it can't read it as a number, so leaves it there, where it is picked up as the next name.

Comment: i want to be able to skip the age part, after entering done as a name, so i don't have to enter a age at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to run your program in VS 2010, and even when I entered a valid number, the program would, to my surprise skip reading the next name.

It seems to me that `cin >> number` doesn't swallow the '\n' I naturally entered after the number.

I attempted adding a call to getchar() after each `cin >> number` and the program suprisingly started working as expected.

So the conclusion is, that you should clean()/ignore() after `cin >> number` even after the number entered was OK, or resort to using getline() (and then parsing) for reading numbers.

If you want not to input "done"'s age then you have to break out of the loop immediately after it's entered. My final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    string name;
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Your name: " ;
        getline(cin, name);
        if(name == "done") 
            break;
        cout <<name<< " age: " ;
        cin >> number;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone enters an invalid age, i.e. something that isn't a number, you need to clear the flags of your cin, and also flush any remaining characters.

```
if( !(cin >> number )
{
     cin.clear();
}
cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() );
```

If it does read a number then you also need to ignore the newline after it.

Comment: This gives me a blank space, after entering a number, i have to enter one more to make the program loop?

Comment: cin has never been my strong point. In practical code I never use it. When you enter the number it terminates with a newline and I question if that remains in the buffer for your next getline call so you might need to skip it (with another ignore) even after a successful read.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter your name: ";
        std::cin >> name;
        if ( "done" == name )
            break;
        std::cout << name << ", please enter your age: ";
        std::cin >> age;
        std::cout << name << ", you are " << age << " years old\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Bye.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Mixing use of `getline()` and `>>` can be problematic. Best to just avoid it if you can. You could also use `getline()` for both, and convert the `int` using a `stringstream`, or possibly `atoi()`, but I don't like that much.

Answer (score 1):

Use the std namespace

This way

```
int number;
string name;
do
{
std::cout<<"Your name: " ;
std::cin>>name;    
std::cout<<name<<" age: " ;
std::cin>>number;
}
while (name!="done");
```

Or this

```
using namspace std;
int number;
    string name;
    do
    {
    std::cout<<"Your name: " ;
    std::cin>>name;    
    std::cout<<name<<" age: " ;
    std::cin>>number;
    }
    while (name!="done");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you give it a *string* while it expect an *int* as `age`.

At the end of the first iterate, as you typed the *Enter* key to input the `age`, an extra *newline* was taken into the `cin`. So in the second iterate, the *newline* showed up as an empty line, causing the `name` to be set as an empty string. Then the program wanted an *int* as `age`. If you are not careful enough, you would input a string and cause the program crash.

One suggestion:
To replace:

```
getline(cin, name);
```

with:

```
do {
    getline(cin, name);    
} while (name.empty());
```